# Scaling Google Map and created polyline on Android

Tags: android, dictionary, scale, polyline

I have created Android application where you can add points on map and then it creates polygon from those points. Which looks something like:

[image]

Then I am saving image of polyline like this:

```
private Bitmap createPolylineBitmap() {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getView().getWidth(), ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getView().getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    //Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getView().getWidth(), ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getView().getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.purple));
    paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    paint.setDither(true);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    ArrayList<LatLng> coordinates = Mainigie.PievienotasKoordinates;

    for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.size(); i++) {
        try {
            LatLng latLng1 = new LatLng(coordinates.get(i).latitude, coordinates.get(i).longitude);
            LatLng latLng2 = new LatLng(coordinates.get(i + 1).latitude, coordinates.get(i + 1).longitude);
            canvas.drawLine((LatLngToPoint(latLng1).x), ((LatLngToPoint(latLng1).y)), (LatLngToPoint(latLng2).x), (LatLngToPoint(latLng2).y), paint);
            canvas.drawCircle((LatLngToPoint(latLng1).x),(LatLngToPoint(latLng1).y),5, paint);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
        }
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

This code creates me image that looks like:

[image]

What I need is this polyline image to be scaled to 1:10000 or 1:5000 in relation to google map. And I need this image to be about 400x400 big, because I need it to be used in PDF document where the scale is very important.

How can I set Google map to these scales?

How can I convert polyline image to those scales?

**EDIT:**
What I think Im doing wrong is using coordinates from the View as Javier Delgado below says. Now im trying to use the coordinates from map but how to transform them to screen coordinates?

**EDIT:**
These are the real map coordinates that creates polygon above

```
    X:         Y:
    57.567177, 25.383375
    57.567391, 25.384218
    57.568717, 25.382321
    57.568159, 25.382033
```

How can I create polyline Bitmap from these coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

You are currently getting the coordinates from the View. However, I think you are looking for the actual coordinates of the map.

You can use `getCameraPosition()`,  `getMyLocation()`, `getProjection()`, `getUiSettings()` and several others that will give you information about the map, not the view:

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap

For example, the `CameraPosition` object will give you the coordinates of the current piece of map visible to the user:

```
bearing - Direction that the camera is pointing in, in degrees clockwise from north.
target - The location that the camera is pointing at.
tilt - The angle, in degrees, of the camera angle from the nadir (directly facing the Earth).
Zoom - level near the center of the screen.
```

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/CameraPosition

And `VisibleRegion`

```
farLeft - LatLng object that defines the far left corner of the camera.
farRight - LatLng object that defines the far right corner of the camera.
latLngBounds - The smallest bounding box that includes the visible region defined in this class.
nearLeft - LatLng object that defines the bottom left corner of the camera.
nearRight - LatLng object that defines the bottom right corner of the camera.
```

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/VisibleRegion

Then you can use this information to make the calculations that your Bitmap needs.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/CameraPosition

Comment: If I actual coordinates of map what would be those calculations to create Bitmap of polyline in scale that I need? This is the first time Im using maps and trying to make any calculations.

Comment: There are tools that can transform geo data distances and sizes. You need to operate with the map locations of the camera and the dots that the user selects.

Answer (score 1):

Anyway, you can convert `LatLng` coordinates into "flat" screen `x,y` coordinates with [`GoogleMap.getProjection().toScreenLocation()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/Projection.html#toScreenLocation(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng)) method and than perform [scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaling_(geometry)) on screen `x,y` coordinates around center of polygon.

For scaling around center of polygon you should implement some more Affine transformations: convert LatLon coordinates of your polygon/rectangle to screen coordinates, move center of polygon to screen coords (0,0), multiply screen coords by scale coeff. You can use something like this:

```
private static List<Point> scalePolygonPoints(List<LatLng> points, float scale, Projection projection) {
    List<Point> scaledPoints = new ArrayList(points.size());

    LatLng polygonCenter = getPolygonCenterPoint(points);
    Point centerPoint = projection.toScreenLocation(polygonCenter);

    for (int i=0; i < points.size(); i++) {
        Point screenPosition = projection.toScreenLocation(points.get(i));
        screenPosition.x = (int) (scale * (screenPosition.x - centerPoint.x) + centerPoint.x);
        screenPosition.y = (int) (scale * (screenPosition.y - centerPoint.y) + centerPoint.y);
        scaledPoints.add(screenPosition);
    }

    return scaledPoints;
}

private static LatLng getPolygonCenterPoint(List<LatLng> polygonPointsList){
    LatLng centerLatLng = null;
    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    for(int i = 0; i < polygonPointsList.size() ; i++) {
        builder.include(polygonPointsList.get(i));
    }
    LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
    centerLatLng =  bounds.getCenter();
    return centerLatLng;
}
```

Usage:

```
...
scaleFactor = 500.0f;
Projection projection = mGoogleMap.getProjection();
List<Point> scaledPoints = scalePolygonPoints(mPolygon.getPoints(), scaleFactor , projection);
// draw scaledPoints on Bitmap canvas
...
```

Comment: If polygon goes out of screen it is not visible on bitmap. Also if I move camera, or zoom coordinates also change. How can I make it to draw the same size polygon on all devices not depending on zoom, or camera position?

Comment: @WhizBoy Please create separate question.

Comment: @ Andrii Omelchenko https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54065575/android-save-polygon-from-map-as-bitmap-same-size-for-all-devices