# Android save polygon from map as bitmap same size for all devices

Tags: android, dictionary, scale, polygon

I am drawing polygon on Google map and it works great. What I need is to save this polygon as bitmap for fixed scale. I am using this code to do that.

```
private static List<Point> scalePolygonPoints(List<LatLng> points, float scale, Projection projection) {
    List<Point> scaledPoints = new ArrayList(points.size());

    LatLng polygonCenter = getPolygonCenterPoint(points);
    Point centerPoint = projection.toScreenLocation(polygonCenter);

    for (int i=0; i < points.size(); i++) {
        Point screenPosition = projection.toScreenLocation(points.get(i));
        screenPosition.x = (int) (scale * (screenPosition.x - centerPoint.x) + centerPoint.x);
        screenPosition.y = (int) (scale * (screenPosition.y - centerPoint.y) + centerPoint.y);
        scaledPoints.add(screenPosition);
    }

    return scaledPoints;
}

private static LatLng getPolygonCenterPoint(List<LatLng> polygonPointsList){
    LatLng centerLatLng = null;
    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    for(int i = 0; i < polygonPointsList.size() ; i++) {
        builder.include(polygonPointsList.get(i));
    }
    LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
    centerLatLng =  bounds.getCenter();
    return centerLatLng;
}
```

And then to create bitmap

```
private Bitmap createPolylineBitmap(List<Point> scaledPoints) {
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(800, 600, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.black));
            paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
            paint.setDither(true);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);


            for (int i = 0; i < scaledPoints.size(); i++) {
                try {
                    canvas.drawLine(scaledPoints.get(i).x, scaledPoints.get(i).y, scaledPoints.get(i + 1).x, scaledPoints.get(i + 1).y, paint);
                }
                catch(Exception ex){
                    canvas.drawLine(scaledPoints.get(i).x, scaledPoints.get(i).y, scaledPoints.get(0).x, scaledPoints.get(0).y, paint);
                }
            }
            return bitmap;
        }
```

The problem is that this method uses screen projection and when user changes zoom or drags map it changes polygon position on bitmap or its even out of bounds. How can I make it to draw the same size polygon on all devices not depending on zoom, or camera position?

**EDIT:**
So basically I managed to get the right size of polygon zooming map at right position before saving it to bitmap. But the problem is when I use device with different resoulution the polygon size is also changing. How to prevent that?

Comment: Is there any reason for why you are saving the polygon as bitmap? Why not just save the LatLng and redraw the polygon using THOSE LatLng.

Comment: I need to save a picture of that polyline.

Answer (score 1):

A clever hack that might work for you- why not manually zoom the camera to fit the polyline whenever user tries to save the geofence.

```
 val latLngs = getLatLngs()
 val builder = LatLngBounds.Builder()
 latLngs.forEach {
        builder.include(it.position)
 }
 val padding = 200
 val bounds = builder.build()
 val cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding)
 map.moveCamera(cameraUpdate)
 //Do your projection operation here...
```

Comment: I tried this and it works. But the problem is when I use device with different resoulution I get different size polygon.

Answer (score 1):

Save an svg image of your polygon. svg is vectoriel, bitmap is not

Comment: How can I convert Google map polygon to svg?

Comment: I would mean instead of creating bitmap create  svg component with svg polygons inside

Comment: I got that but do you have any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: You have to use a svg render API. eg the androidsvg api. https://bigbadaboom.github.io/androidsvg/